# How to find all .PNG files and move them in new folders like 1,2,3,4,5.. (one file per folder)

Tags: bash, xargs

I would like to find .png files in current sub-folders and move them in new folders. I need one .png file, per single folder. Folders needs to be auto-created. I tried something like below, but doesn't work. Please help me.

```
#!/bin/bash
find . -name "*.png" -print0 | \
sort -z --version-sort | \
xargs -0n1 bash -c 'TARGET=target-$((${1//[^0-9]/} "/ 0 + 1)); \
mkdir -p "$TARGET"; \
mv -t "$TARGET" "$@"' move-1
```

Comment: If you can post a simple input and desired output, that would be great. Because in your code, you're diving by zero `0` and add `+ 1` and a double quote inside the arithmetic expression...

Comment: I would like simply re-organize .png files and move them from current folders to completly new folders. New folders needs to be numbered like 1,2,3,4.. - but inside those new folders needs to be just 1 moved .png file. Any solution would be great. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you use `sort`? Should the files in the new directory keep the old name?

Comment: Not sure why i used sort. But yes, files needs to keep the old filename.

Comment: _Not sure why i used sort_  :  Well, you wrote the program, so you should know what are you doing (hoping that you don't suffer from multiple-personalities....). The sorting will have the effect that the created directories get different timestamps based on the version number, but in what way are you going to exploit this property later? Also, what is the meaning of the `move-1` in your `mv` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

n=1
find . -name '*.png' -print0 | {
  while IFS= read -rd '' pic; do
    while [[ -e $n ]]; do
      ((n++))
    done
    mkdir -vp "$n" && mv -v "$pic" "$n"
  done
}
```

---

Tested against the files and directories, created by:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mkdir -p foo/bar/baz/more/qux

touch foo/bar/{a..c}.png
touch foo/bar/baz/{d..f}.png
touch foo/bar/baz/more/{g..i}.png
touch foo/bar/baz/more/qux/{j..l}.png
```

---

Output

```
mkdir: created directory '1'
renamed './foo/bar/a.png' -> '1/a.png'
mkdir: created directory '2'
renamed './foo/bar/b.png' -> '2/b.png'
mkdir: created directory '3'
renamed './foo/bar/baz/d.png' -> '3/d.png'
mkdir: created directory '4'
renamed './foo/bar/baz/e.png' -> '4/e.png'
mkdir: created directory '5'
renamed './foo/bar/baz/f.png' -> '5/f.png'
mkdir: created directory '6'
renamed './foo/bar/baz/more/g.png' -> '6/g.png'
mkdir: created directory '7'
renamed './foo/bar/baz/more/h.png' -> '7/h.png'
mkdir: created directory '8'
renamed './foo/bar/baz/more/i.png' -> '8/i.png'
mkdir: created directory '9'
renamed './foo/bar/baz/more/qux/j.png' -> '9/j.png'
mkdir: created directory '10'
renamed './foo/bar/baz/more/qux/k.png' -> '10/k.png'
mkdir: created directory '11'
renamed './foo/bar/baz/more/qux/l.png' -> '11/l.png'
mkdir: created directory '12'
renamed './foo/bar/c.png' -> '12/c.png'
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use a counter in a `while` loop:

```
find . -name "*.png" -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' f ; do
    c=$((c+1));
    mkdir "$c";
    mv -v "$f" "$c";
  done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your logic and integrate with below logic. Here is full command

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" -print -exec mkdir {}.folder   \;  | xargs -I {} mv {} {}.folder
```

- Below command will find png, `-exec` will create folder. `-print` is important to pass result next XARGS.

```
find . -type f -name "*.png" -print -exec mkdir {}.folder   \;
```

- And this line will move files accordingly to next folder.

```
xargs -I {} mv {} {}.folder
```

You can change folder path accodring your requirement.